# Stored procedure issue not working correcty

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql stored procedure, and I am having an issue with a stored procedure. 
I have a variable (order_status) in a dropdown, and when the user selects, it stores text value in database..

```
-- Order status: 1 = Pending; 2 = Processing; 3 = Rejected; 4 = Completed
```

I would appreciate any advice..

```
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN order_status = 'Pending' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS 'Pending'
FROM
    sales_orders;


CREATE PROCEDURE orderStatus()
BEGIN
    SELECT 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN order_status = 'Pending' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
```

This does not give me any results..

Thanks

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking.  Your first SQL statement has a `BEGIN` which doesn't seem to belong, and your second SQL statement has an unclosed parentheses.  Neither of these seem syntactically valid.  Which one are you trying to execute?  What specifically are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

I have a column in db which shows order_status (i.e. 1, 2, 3... - tinyint) . When an item is selected it passes a string value to db. I get an error does not identify variable 'order_status'.